Tool or plugin in QGIS that allows seeing measurements/area of polygon/line while drawing it
I am looking for either a tool or plugin in QGIS that allows me to view measurements and/or area while creating a ploygon/line. I know I can measure it afterwards, but I am specifically looking for a tool/plugin that will show me in real time how many m2/ha a polygon is while I am drawing it. Potentially also the length of the sides of the polygon if possible.
Does this community know if any such tool/plugin exists?
